# What does "position" in "each position in the decoder" denote in the Transformer's original paper?

Tags: terminology, papers, transformer, attention

I am reading [Attention is All You Need](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.03762) and I feel confused about the word "position" in this paper, by the way I'm not native English speaker which may cause my confusion which has confused me for a few days.

In this paragraph from 3.2.3 of the paper,

> Similarly, self-attention layers in the decoder allow each position in the decoder to attend to all positions in the decoder up to and including that position. We need to prevent leftward information flow in the decoder to preserve the auto-regressive property. We implement this inside of scaled dot-product attention by masking out (setting to −∞) all values in the input of the softmax which correspond to illegal connections.

"each position in the decoder", where is it actually, in which part of decoder? What does "each position in the decoder" really want to mean? Each layer in the decoder? Or something else like position of vectors? And what does "all positions" mean? Same with the former "position"? Could you please give an example to explain?

I've already known how masked attention works. It uses masking to prevent the encoder from attending to positions in outputs it should't attend to during training because entire translation'd be given when training.